# Как правильно располагать ссылку в строке, содержащей знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

В современном интернете мы часто сталкиваемся с написанием сообщений с использованием разметки. Я до сих пор не могу найти правила, четко говорящего, что правильно, включать или не включать знаки препинания и т. д. в ссылку.

Например.

- «[Кавычки](https://rus.stackexchange.com/)» или [«кавычки»](https://rus.stackexchange.com/).
- [Все предложение с точкой.](https://rus.stackexchange.com/) [Или без](https://rus.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Краткая формула.

Знаки препинания всегда следует оставлять вне ссылки, кроме случаев:

1. Предложение целиком является ссылкой (Visit W3Schools.com!). Это же относится к заголовкам.
2. Кавычки входят в гиперссылку, если являются частью сложного названия (Шоколадная фабрика «Шахразада»).

Не видел, чтобы это было написано явно. Вероятно, наиболее разумная тактика следовать признанным авторитетам, например:  http://www.w3.org/ или 
https://www.artlebedev.ru/kovodstvo/sections/83/

Comment: Жалко, что нет конкретного правила языка. Приведенные вами ссылки все-таки рекомендации.