# Знаки препинания, примыкающие к курсиву, жирному и другому шрифту

Tags: пунктуация

Был уже [аналогичный вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/418515/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) насчёт кавычек, и ответ на него кажется правильным и убедительным, но не хватает всё-таки источника, где это было бы сформулировано как правило.

А как быть со знаками препинания, окружающими текст, написанный курсивом, жирным или подчёркнутым шрифтом в случае скобок, кавычек и точки, запятой, "?", "!", двоеточия после такого текста? Делать эти знаки такими же, как текст, или "обычными"? Тире я не рассматриваю, поскольку оно отделяется пробелом.

***Мои размышления:***

Мне кажется, что в случае со скобками и кавычками нужно их делать такими же, если ***всё, что внутри,*** полностью написано курсивом, либо жирным, либо подчёркнутым, либо комбинацией, но одинаково. Если только часть такая, то скобки или кавычки будут обычные.

А вот с другими знаками препинания в конце "специального" текста ***не на всё предложение*** вообще непонятно. С одной стороны хочется сделать этот знак таким же (особенно двоеточие), а с другой стороны странно делать, например, *курсивной* ***точку*** или ***"?"*** в предложении, большая часть которого написана не курсивом. ***Особенно странно*** делать запятые, выделяющие какой-то ***оборот,*** разными, как я тут продемонстрировал.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Знаки препинания, примыкающие к курсиву, жирному и другому шрифту, имеют то же начертание и степень жирности, что предшествующее слово.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но к этим указаниям надо относиться... э-э, творчески. Можно выбирать. Чтоб глаз не резало!

Роберт Брингхерст ("Основы стиля в типографике") советует в случае выделения слов жирным знаки препинания оставлять светлыми, а в случае курсива и знаки препинания делать курсивными.

> ***В случае смешанных начертаний*** почти во всех случаях знак препинания
> должен быть того же начертания, что и слово, к которому он примыкает.
> Лучший совет дизайнеру и верстальщику в таких случаях: **не надо
> бояться.**

См. также: [Знаки препинания в нестандартных ситуациях](https://www.artlebedev.ru/kovodstvo/sections/143/).

Изучайте нижерекомендованное, но несогласная я!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Согласна, что квадратную или фигурную скобку, закрывающую курсив, но открывшуюся ранее его, следует оставить "своей". То же после полужирного.

Все прочие знаки - точка, запятая, двоеточие, тэзэ, вопрос, клик (термины) и кавычка - сохраняют шрифтовое выделение.

Comment: Спасибо, Галина! Стало быть, Вы считаете, что так и надо делать, как я сделал в последнем предложении, так что оборот получился выделенным разными запятыми?

Comment: Угу. Это не страшно. Но противоречит  ЦУ к оформлению курсово-дипломных работ. Нужно смотреть в конкретном случае; есть такой редакторский подход "смотрится - не смотрится". Возможно какое-то короткое слово, скажем закурсивленное "увы", будет смотреться иначе...